# Pagination pages not working, After removing product-category from url?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, pagination, woocommerce

For a woocommerce website I have to removed "product-category" and "product-tag" from my url.

http://example.com/product-category/latest-bridal-wear/

Below .htaccess code is not working with category pagination pages like 

 http://example.com/product-category/latest-bridal-wear/page/2/

```
RewriteRule ^/product-category/(.+)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/product-category/(.+)$ http://example.com/$1
```

I just need code that remove "product-category" from url and works with pagination pages as well.

I know it will be bad idea if we follow UX and woocommerce rules but i need it badly without any plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Some servers handle rewrite rules differently especially shared hosting plans but i think the redirect you need will be more like this. Will work for links to your site but will not do anything about pagination links generated by your site.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /product-category(.*) //$1
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. 
my code already working and removing "product-category" but i just need code for pagination. 
Are you saying its not possible ?

Comment: Not saying its impossible You only asked about the links not working in your question when removing Tags and Categories